# Low quality of capture view context on iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, sdk

I need capture specific UIView , but the result is in low quality how can fix this and increase the quality ?

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(captureView.bounds.size);
    [captureView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, nil, nil, nil);
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: you can try with this also UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);

Comment: When you say "low quality" what exactly do you mean?  The image doesn't look the same as what's on the screen?  Are you using a retina display but the captured image isn't as sharp? Is the image grainy or distorted?  What is exactly wrong with it?

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot of what is being captured and also the resulting image?

Comment: Did you put the suggested `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` before your call to `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext`?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is in your capturing code? `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);` makes a direct screenshot. What i mean is: how are you testing the results - by showing them from code or do you check the files? Are you doing this on simulator or actual device...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I guess you need a capture a UIView/UIWindow in retina resolution (960x640 or 2048x1536) Using UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions and set its scale parameter 0.0f makes it capture in native resolution (retina for iPhone 4 and later or iPad 3).

This code capture your UIView in native resolution

```
CGRect rect = [captureView bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,YES,0.0f);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[captureView.layer renderInContext:context];   
UIImage *capturedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This one does the same for full screen (key window)

```
UIWindow *keyWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
CGRect rect = [keyWindow bounds];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size,YES,0.0f);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[keyWindow.layer renderInContext:context];   
UIImage *capturedScreen = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

This saves the UIImage in jpg format with 95% quality in the app's document folder

```
NSString  *imagePath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Documents/capturedImage.jpg"]];    
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(capturedImage, 0.95) writeToFile:imagePath atomically:YES];
```