# iOS capture view with background thread

Tags: ios, screen-capture, ipad-3

I'm not sure how to efficiently capture the screen on a pixel-dense iOS device such as the iPad 3 (2048x1536). I've seen some examples such as [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1704/_index.html) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891772/low-quality-of-capture-view-context-on-ipad):

However, these solutions are too slow. I would like the view to be periodically captured maybe a few times a second, but the capturing mechanism is slow enough that if I executed this in the main thread, the UI would lock up. I was wondering whether it's possible to somehow delegate this to a background thread? Or perhaps there's a more efficient view capturing function? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my experience, on iPad 3, `UIGetScreenImage()` is fast enough.

Comment: Last I heard, apps were being rejected for using the `UIGetScreenImage()` private api method, os it might not be an option here.